# What is the product of $\frac{a}{b}\left(\frac{a}{b}-1\right)\left(\frac{a}{b}-2\right)\cdots\left(\frac{a}{b}-(n-1)\right)$?

Tags: calculus

Let's suppose that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers so that $\frac{a}{b}$ is a fraction (a rational number) where $a<b$ and $a\not=0$ and $b\not=0$ (an example of such fraction is $\frac{2}{3}$).

Can we find a formula for the following product?

$$
\left(\frac{a}{b}-0\right)\left(\frac{a}{b}-1\right)\left(\frac{a}{b}-2\right)\left(\frac{a}{b}-3\right)\cdots\left(\frac{a}{b}-(n-1)\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no "simple" formula that lets you calculate this value. For these kinds of products the notation of the [Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) was introduced.